# How can I calculate UPS shipping using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, xml, curl, node.js, ups

I'm developing a public e-commerce site in NodeJS and MongoDB, and I'm using forever instead of nginx or anything like that. (please let me know if I'm totally insane for doing this and why before I get too far along :)

As part of this site I need to calculate shipping, but I need to know that the numbers are spot on because I want to charge customers at checkout.

How could I set this up with Node.js?

I kind of have [one solution](https://gist.github.com/1174294), but I have no guarantee that it's accurate. Has anyone dealt with the UPS APIs using Node?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: My last brush with the UPS xml apis made me want to bury my head in the sand (using PHP as the environment). Bad documentation, incorrect documentation, blah blah blah. T'was quite the fun project.

Comment: There is an API for this explicit reason... You'll have a WAY better shot at doing this if you localize the API calls and use their system than hacking something together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a node module with support for more functionality (and will continue improving) of the UPS API. With this module you can provide rating information, create a shipment, produce a label, void a shipment, track shipments, and perform address validation.

Check it out:

`npm install shipping-ups`

Read docs here: https://github.com/typefoo/node-shipping-ups

Comment: Obrigado! This looks like a legitimate up-to-date npm module with documentation. It would be nice to eventually abstract your module to include other shipping providers. There are many applications for such a module. Best of luck!

Comment: FYI to those newcomers –– this project is both deprecated and dead.

Answer (score 2):

Someone named Jesse D. Pate has developed a native UPS API. I have no idea if it's worthwhile, but the github repo is [here](http://github.com/jessedpate/ups_node), and it can be installed and toyed around with via

```
npm install ups_node
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got it figured out ...now to start a Github project

This is a universal way to do it:

I modified the `./RatingPackage/PACKAGEXMLTools/Rate_Tool_SampleRequest.xml` to include my information then I saved it as `testRequest.xml` then I posted it to https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate (their test server) using the command

> curl -X POST -d "`less testRequest.xml`" https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate

and it returns an XML document that can then be converted to the (superior) json format and used in a web app.